How to allow week ca md for Openvpn on Ubuntu 24.04LTS
I have an old Openvpn server which use AES-256-CBC as cipher.  When I used 22.04 I could workaround with tls-cipher=DEFAULT:SECLEVEL=0 in the openssl config file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections.  But after upgraded to 24.04, this directory is empty.  I asked Gemini AI and it suggests that I add a system_default_sect section with CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0 in my /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf but that did not work.  I can use sudo openvpn --config xxx.ovpn --tls-cipher="DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0" to connect but that is too tedious.
So how can I connect without opening a terminal and sudo openvpn --tls-cipher?
